# jQuery object undefined yet it can be printed just fine and I can't access its properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

Directing your attention to the 2nd console.log, that is where I continually get "error: last_pos is undefined" even though the console.logs surrounding it work fine and print last_pos which has two int properties named "top" and "left". No matter if I try dot notation or bracket notation, I get the error. How can such a contradiction happen?

```
  var last_dropped_id = '';
  var last_pos = '';
  $( ".drop-area" ).droppable({

   tolerance: "touch",
drop: function( event, ui ) {

  var valMy = "center";
  var valAt = "top center";
  if(last_dropped_id != undefined){
    var last_pos = $(last_dropped_id).position();

    console.log(last_pos);
    console.log(last_pos['left']);
    console.log("WTF");
    console.log(last_pos);
    //valMy+= "+" + last_pos;
    // valAt+= "+" + last_pos.top;

  }
  var $this = $(this);

  ui.draggable.position({
    my: valMy,
    at: valAt,
    of: $this,
    using: function(pos) {
      $(this).animate(pos, 400, "linear");

   },

  });


    last_dropped_id = '#' + ui.draggable.attr('id');

  console.log(last_dropped_id);
}



});
```

Comment: Mmh, you are initializing `last_dropped_id` with `''`, but check `last_dropped_id != undefined`. So you end up calling `$('').position()` which returns `null`.

Comment: @FelixKling, I see now. I put a new conditional that only tries to access the property if `last_pos != undefined` and it works as I need it to. Thanks